# Model a saturation with only lower limit in simulink

Tags: simulink

I just need a block to model a saturation that gives me zero when the input is under a certain value and the input when it's above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `Threshold` in the `Switch` block to your desired value.

[image]